# Можно ли указать учетную запись для получения файлов из сетевой директории?

Tags: c#

Подскажите, можно ли указать учетную запись для получения файлов из сетевой директории?

К примеру приложение запускается из под user1, но надо чтобы в сетевую директорию "ходил" user2, просто чтобы получить файлы этой директории.

Как пример получения файлов: new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles()